# Creating Custom php login page for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one website, in which there are three wordpress installed under the same domain name.

Now, how i can create a single php login page to login in all the wordpress admin from single login page.

All these three wordpress install has seperate database. I have my own purpose of installing three wordpress under same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own database users table (or use one of your installations as master.)

On this “superlogin” page you are to obtail the credentials, check against your supertable that it’s OK and then call [`wp_set_auth_cookie`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie) on all the installations.

Another option is to create a plugin for “hidden” auth, activate it on all the installations and call it’s `login` methos in a loop from your “superlogin” page.

BTW, why would not you use WPMU?

Comment: Thanks, i am new to wordpress. and i don't know stuff related to wordpress login. after search on net, i came to know that we have to set cookies for login. i have php page that will be in the different directory than three of the wordpress installation. so i will not be able to access any function of wordpress. i need to write php code for all the stuff

Comment: Well, install kinda `OAuth` plugin on all the WPs and use it to login from outside.

Comment: Hey, i found the solution - Install the "infiniteWP" just google it. Very very simple solution